# change temp dir for Neo4j-OGM unit tests?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Out of the box, the junit tests of the [Neo4j-OGM](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm) library create the temporary database files under /tmp.

How can I change this?

Setting java.io.tmpdir in the maven-surefire-plugin config does not seem to do the trick.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <java.io.tmpdir>/alt/tmp</java.io.tmpdir>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
           <systemProperties>
               <property>
                   <name>java.io.tmpdir</name>
                   <value>/path/to/temp</value>
                </property>
           </systemProperties>
     </configuration>
...
</plugin>
```

Update since the syntax above is deprecated:

```
<plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
               <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <java.io.tmpdir>/path/to/temp</java.io.tmpdir> 
               </systemPropertyVariables>
         </configuration>
    ...
    </plugin>
```

Comment: After switching to latest Maven 3.3.3, it actually works as advertised. I had been using Maven 3.1.1.

It works with the new and the deprecated surefire's systemProperties syntax.